# How to remove white space from the text layer in DjVu

Tags: djvu

How to remove spaces and tabs from the text layer in DjVu document for better text search using the [DjVuLibre](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/) library?

By removing unnecessary characters (and their xml tags), also the file size is reduced.

Answer (score 1):

First, use the `djvutoxml` tool to extract a text layer in XML format from the DjVu document.

At the command prompt, type:

```
path\djvutoxml.exe path\book.djvu path\book.xml
```

Instead `path` parameter substitute your location on the disk.

Press Enter...

---

Then, using the *regular expressions*, remove the selected characters
(placed between sharp brackets `> <`). You can use any text editor (that can do regex).

String to remove spaces:

```
<WORD><CHARACTER coords="\d*,\d*,\d*,\d*"> </CHARACTER></WORD>
```

String to remove tabs:

```
<WORD><CHARACTER coords="\d*,\d*,\d*,\d*">&#9;</CHARACTER></WORD>
```

Regular expression can also be written in this form. This deletes everything at once:

```
<WORD><CHARACTER coords="([0-9,]*?)">(&#9;| )</CHARACTER></WORD>
```

Original fragment:

```
<WORD coords="318,262,706,190">Hallo</WORD>
<WORD><CHARACTER coords="707,262,760,190"> </CHARACTER></WORD>
<WORD coords="761,262,813,190">World!</WORD>
<WORD><CHARACTER coords="814,262,860,190"> </CHARACTER></WORD>
```

Fixed fragment:

```
<WORD coords="318,262,706,190">Hallo</WORD>
[here was the code for the space]
<WORD coords="761,262,813,190">World!</WORD>
[here was the code for the space]
```

(You can see how large text strings have been removed. Here **62** characters to describe one space!)

---

Finally, use the `djvuxmlparser` tool to merge modified XML with DjVu document.

At the command prompt, type:

```
path\djvuxmlparser.exe -o path\final.djvu path\book.xml
```

Instead `path` parameter substitute your location on the disk.
Parameter `-o` defines the target file.

Press Enter...